# MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i m beginner in unity , i m trying to make simple ball  game in which i m generating random objects and player have to save the ball from hitting the objects ,also i destroying the objects after ball passes these objects but i m getting this error.

```
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
UnityEngine.Object.Internal_InstantiateSingle (UnityEngine.Object data, UnityEngine.Vector3 pos, UnityEngine.Quaternion rot) (at <9baebf9af86541678fd15bfdbf5f26eb>:0)
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Object original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Quaternion rotation) (at <9baebf9af86541678fd15bfdbf5f26eb>:0)
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Quaternion rotation) (at <9baebf9af86541678fd15bfdbf5f26eb>:0)
ObstacleSpawner.spawner () (at Assets/scripts/ObstacleSpawner.cs:26)
```

myObstacleSpawner script is

```
public class ObstacleSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] obstacle;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{ 
        InvokeRepeating("spawner", 0.5f, 0.5f);
    
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * 50 * Time.deltaTime);
    
}

public void spawner()
{
    Instantiate(obstacle[Random.Range(0, 2)], new Vector3(Random.Range(-3f,3f), transform.position.y, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);

}

}
```

my Destroyer script is

```
public class Destroyer : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
public float speedDestroyer = 10f;
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "enemy")
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}

void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speedDestroyer * Time.deltaTime);
       
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you not understand in the error message? You are destroying objects in your collision method .. seemingly they are used somewhere else after that even though they don't exist anymore ... Are your `obstacles` actual objects from your scene or prefabs that live only in the assets? It seems to me that you destroy the original `obstacles` so the next time you call `Instantiate` it might be destroyed already ...

Comment: Looks like the obstacle prefab(s) are being destroyed rather than the instances?  The error seems to be pointing at the Instantiate call.  Check that you are not destroying the objects in the obstacle array.

Comment: I am getting the same error. But in my case, I am accessing the gameobject that is in my scene rather my actual prefab. How do we get around this issue?